Is it necessary for this function to have first-order derivative continuity?
Consider the initial value problem
$$u_t + b \cdot Du = 0 \quad \text{in}\,\,R^n \times(0, \infty),$$
$$u = g \quad \text{on}\,\,R^n \times \{t = 0\}.$$
The book says that
$$u(x, t) = g(x - tb) \quad x \in R^n, t \geq 0$$
is a solution if $g$ is $C^1$.
Can we ignore the continuity of $g'$ in the proof that it is indeed a solution?
If not, what role does the continuity of $g'$ play in the proof?

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.
